# What is the position in Gantry for slideshow

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using Gantry framework 4 in Joomla3.2 and add an Ice slideshow.  I try placing it in a number of default positions.  The image appears in the position but it won't slide.   If i use T3 framework in Joomla3.2 by creating position5, it slides ok for the same ice product.

I love to use Gantry so how do i fix this.  Thanks mates.

Answer (score 0):

> Have you added **jQuery** to your Gantry template?
>   Can you use firebug to check the error of the page?